# Unable to get HTMLVideoElement object using angular in ionic app

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, camera, mediapipe

I am trying to create a pose detection hybrid app using ionic 5/cordova. I am using mediapipe library to get human pose points and show skeleton on video element. Mediapipe library accepts only `HTMLVideoElement` format.
This code works for web but when I am trying to build android app I am getting this error `Failed to acquire camera feed: NotReadableError: Could not start video source ionic`

This is my Html code

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="container">        
    <video autoplay="true" class="input_video"></video>        
    <canvas class="output_canvas" width="1280px" height="720px"></canvas>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Here is my logic to get camera feed. I am Using Mediapipe library

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  drawConnectors,
  drawLandmarks,
} from '@mediapipe/drawing_utils/drawing_utils';
import { Camera } from '@mediapipe/camera_utils/camera_utils';
import { FACEMESH_TESSELATION, HAND_CONNECTIONS, Holistic, POSE_CONNECTIONS } from '@mediapipe/holistic';

  videoElement: any;
  canvasElement: any;
  canvasCtx: any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.videoElement = document.getElementsByClassName('input_video')[0];
    this.canvasElement = document.getElementsByClassName('output_canvas')[0];
    this.canvasCtx = this.canvasElement.getContext('2d');

    const holistic = new Holistic({
      locateFile: (file) => {
        console.log(`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/holistic/${file}`);
        return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/holistic/${file}`;
      }
    });
    holistic.setOptions({
      modelComplexity: 1,
      smoothLandmarks: true,
      enableSegmentation: true,
      smoothSegmentation: true,
      refineFaceLandmarks: true,
      minDetectionConfidence: 0.5,
      minTrackingConfidence: 0.5
    });
    holistic.onResults(this.onResults.bind(this));    
  
    const camera = new Camera(this.videoElement, {
      onFrame: async () => {
        await holistic.send({ image: this.videoElement });
      },
      width: 1280,
      height: 720
    });
    camera.start();
  }

onResults(results) {
    this.canvasCtx.save();
    this.canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvasElement.width, this.canvasElement.height);
    this.canvasCtx.drawImage(results.segmentationMask, 0, 0,
      this.canvasElement.width, this.canvasElement.height);

    // Only overwrite existing pixels.
    this.canvasCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
    this.canvasCtx.fillStyle = '#00FF00';
    this.canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvasElement.width, this.canvasElement.height);

    // Only overwrite missing pixels.
    this.canvasCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
    this.canvasCtx.drawImage(
      results.image, 0, 0, this.canvasElement.width, this.canvasElement.height);

    this.canvasCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    drawConnectors(this.canvasCtx, results.poseLandmarks, POSE_CONNECTIONS,
      { color: '#00FF00', lineWidth: 4 });
    drawLandmarks(this.canvasCtx, results.poseLandmarks,
      { color: '#FF0000', lineWidth: 2 });
    drawConnectors(this.canvasCtx, results.faceLandmarks, FACEMESH_TESSELATION,
      { color: '#C0C0C070', lineWidth: 1 });
    drawConnectors(this.canvasCtx, results.leftHandLandmarks, HAND_CONNECTIONS,
      { color: '#CC0000', lineWidth: 5 });
    drawLandmarks(this.canvasCtx, results.leftHandLandmarks,
      { color: '#00FF00', lineWidth: 2 });
    drawConnectors(this.canvasCtx, results.rightHandLandmarks, HAND_CONNECTIONS,
      { color: '#00CC00', lineWidth: 5 });
    drawLandmarks(this.canvasCtx, results.rightHandLandmarks,
      { color: '#FF0000', lineWidth: 2 });
    this.canvasCtx.restore();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get Video Element via `ElementRef`;

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

export class YourComponent {
  @ViewChild('videoPlayer', { static: false }) videoplayer: ElementRef;

  getVideo(event: any) {
    console.log(this.videoplayer);
  }

}
```

in HTML:

```
<video #videoPlayer controls>
    <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type='video/webm' />
</video>
```